# How to make Jmeter version 3.12 script running into older version 2.11?

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, version

I created a Jmeter script that runs with version 3.12 on my local and it works. 
I need to run it through Jenkins where Jmeter Version 2.12 is installed. 
When I try to run the same test plan with Jenkins it shows error 
`ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration' : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'`

Can anyone suggest how to make it run with the lower version? Is it possible to run it with version 2.12 with out any error?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically is should not be a problem to run the test on older JMeter version, just make sure it is not impacted by one of the [incompatible changes](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html#Incompatible%20changes) so inspect [JMeter Changes history](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html) and amend your script accordingly.

In regards to your question itself, it looks like you are using a [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) with `Save sent bytes count` option enabled somewhere in your Test Plan.

[image: JMeter Listener Configuration]

If this is the case - just delete the Listener(s) and your test should work normally. Also be aware that having listeners in the test plan is some form of [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) as they are very resource intensive and given you are storing results into .jtl file, aren't you, they are not required at all. See [Greedy Listeners - Memory Leeches of Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) article for details.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T, Thanks for the help. I disabled that listener from my test plan. But still I have same issue while running script.

Comment: ```2017/06/05 06:30:40 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration' : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'```

Comment: You need to **delete** the listener, disabling won't do the trick as JMeter will still try to process it

Comment: Yep, That error gone.  But this time I have different error.  :( So many errors just because of version.  Can you help? `2017/06/05 11:00:36 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Unable to load or invoke class: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC4CookieHandler org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Comment: Well, try deleting [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) from the 3.2 test plan and add it in 2.12 test plan.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri your suggestion worked for me.  Now I have same compatibility issue with BeanShellSampler too.I'm pasting the error here...  Can you suggest how to overcome this error?

Comment: ---- Debugging information ----
message             : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[2]/BeanShellSampler